# Не работает шорткод внутри шорткода спойлера

Tags: php, wordpress, шорткод

Есть сайт на `wordpress`. На одной из страниц хочу вложить один шорткод в другой вот такой записью:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[spoiler name="ФОРМА ЗАЯВКИ" ][contact-form-7 id="36762" title="Форма-заявка"][/spoiler]'); ?>
```

но, первый отрабатывает, а второй с `contact-form-7` - нет. 
По отдельности работают оба. Почему и как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы можно было использовать вложенные шорткоды, функция внешнего шорткода должна вызывать `do_shortcode($content);`.

```
add_shortcode( 'my_shortcode', 'my_shortcode_fn' );
function my_shortcode_fn($atts, $content){
  echo do_shortcode($content);
}
```

Смотрите код шорткода `spoiler`.

Answer (score 0):

@Ponio все гораздо проще - достаточно записать вот такую конструкцию:

```
<?php
$form = do_shorcode('[contact-form-7 id="36762" title="Форма-заявка"]');
echo do_shortcode('[spoiler name="ФОРМА ЗАЯВКИ" ]'.$form.'[/spoiler]');
?>
```